# Whats SoundFx In Automatic Call recorder (CAllU)

Tags: java, android, record

I develop a Call recorder But in some Devices one side record calls so i test other call recorder i find a call recorder (callU)
in CallU use SoundFX  Record call two side
now my question: Whats SoundFX?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADRAn.jpg)

Comment: I find in liberty callU "libaudio-record.so" maybe SoundFx = "libaudio-record.so" How add "libaudio-record.so" to projects?